# How to load an object of the correct type into a collection before performing the "TRead.ReadProp" procedure

Tags: delphi, collections, components

I am creating a set of properties in a collection item. Each item has a different set of properties according to its type:

```pascal
  type
    TMyProps = class(TPersistent)
  private
    Fcommom: boolean;
    procedure Setcommom(const Value: boolean);
    published
      property commom: boolean read Fcommom write Setcommom;
    end;
    TMyPropsClass = class of TMyProps;

    TFieldPropsFloat = class(TMyProps)
  private
    FDecimalplaces: integer;
    procedure SetDecimalplaces(const Value: integer);
    published
      property Decimalplaces: integer read FDecimalplaces write SetDecimalplaces;
    end;

    TFieldPropsStr = class(TMyProps)
  private
    FLength: integer;
    procedure SetLength(const Value: integer);
    published
      property Length: integer read FLength write SetLength;
    end;

    TMyCollection = class(TOwnedCollection)
    end;

    TMyItem = class(TCollectionItem)
    private
      FMyPropsClass: TMyPropsClass;
      FMyProps: TMyProps;
      procedure ReadMyProps(Reader: TReader);
      procedure WriteMyProps(Writer: TWriter);
      procedure RecreateMyProps;
    procedure SetMyProps(const Value: TMyProps);
    procedure SetMyPropsClass(const Value: TMyPropsClass);
    protected
      procedure DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler); override;
    public
      procedure AfterConstruction; override;
    published
      property MyPropsClass: TMyPropsClass read FMyPropsClass write SetMyPropsClass;
      property MyProps: TMyProps read FMyProps write SetMyProps stored false;
    end;
```

in 'TMyItem' an error occurs while loading properties written to '.dfm' file because 'MyProps' has not yet been built with 'MyPropsClass' properties that have not yet been loaded from '.dfm'

How to solve it? Is this the best approach?

Edit: Also, I'm trying to follow the tip Remy Lebeau gave me(comments bellow), but, I can't write in every item on the list.

```pascal
///...

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TMyComponent]);
end;


procedure TMyItem.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  FMyPropsClass := TFieldPropsStr;
  RecreateMyProps;
end;

procedure TMyItem.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
begin
  inherited DefineProperties(Filer);
  Filer.DefineProperty('MyProps', ReadMyProps, WriteMyProps, True);
end;

type
 TReaderAccess = class(TReader);
 TWriterAccess = class(TWriter);

procedure TMyItem.ReadMyProps(Reader: TReader);
begin
  MyProps := TMyPropsClass(FindClass(Reader.ReadString)).Create;
  Reader.CheckValue(vaCollection);
  Reader.ReadListBegin;
  while not Reader.EndOfList do
    TReaderAccess(Reader).ReadProperty(MyProps);
  Reader.ReadListEnd;
  Reader.ReadListEnd;
end;

procedure TMyItem.RecreateMyProps;
begin
  if FMyProps <> nil then
     FMyProps.Free;

  FMyProps := FMyPropsClass.Create;
end;

procedure TMyItem.SetMyProps(const Value: TMyProps);
begin
  FMyProps := Value;
end;

procedure TMyItem.SetMyPropsClass(const Value: TMyPropsClass);
begin
  if FMyPropsClass <> Value then
  begin
    FMyPropsClass := Value;
    RecreateMyProps;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyItem.WriteMyProps(Writer: TWriter);
begin
  Writer.WriteString(MyProps.ClassName); //if comments this line, write fine

  TWriterAccess(Writer).WriteValue(vaCollection);
  Writer.WriteListBegin;
  Writer.WriteProperties(MyProps);
  Writer.WriteListEnd;
  Writer.WriteListEnd;
end;


{ TMyProps }

procedure TMyProps.Setcommom(const Value: boolean);
begin
  Fcommom := Value;
end;

{ TFieldPropsFloat }

procedure TFieldPropsFloat.SetDecimalplaces(const Value: integer);
begin
  FDecimalplaces := Value;
end;

{ TFieldPropsStr }

procedure TFieldPropsStr.SetLength(const Value: integer);
begin
  FLength := Value;
end;

{ TButton1 }

procedure TMyComponent.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  FMyCollection := TMyCollection.Create(Self, TMyItem);
end;

procedure TMyComponent.SetMyCollection(const Value: TMyCollection);
begin
  FMyCollection := Value;
end;
```

How correctly implements `ReadMyProps` and `WriteMyProps` procedures for each item of collection?

Comment: Mark the `MyProps` property as `stored=false` (or don't make it `published` at all) and then override the virtual [`DefineProperties()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TPersistent.DefineProperties) method to stream the `MyProps` data manually. See [Storing and Loading Unpublished Properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Storing_and_Loading_Unpublished_Properties):[Overriding the DefineProperties Method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Overriding_the_DefineProperties_Method) in Embarcadero's DocWiki for more details

Comment: thanks, but i need that 'MyProps' are visible in object inpector.  Is it possible to do this with your suggestion?

Comment: "*i need that 'MyProps' are visible in object inpector*" - that is where the `stored=false` directive comes into play. See [Storage Specifiers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties_(Delphi)#Storage_Specifiers) for more details. And then overriding `DefineProperties()` can stream data manually that the property no longer streams natively. That way, you have more control over what is written to the DFM and how it is written, and how it is read back out.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you for the tips, but, i'm really confusing about how implement this. Could you give me a simple example showing 'DefineProperties' with a 'Reader' and 'Writer' procedure to each collectionItem?

Comment: I have posted an answer now.  I was not suggesting overriding `DefineProperties()` on your `TComponent` but on `TMyItem` itself.

Comment: Where did `TOwnedpersistent` come from? That is not a standard Delphi class

Comment: sorry, this is a error

Answer (score 0):

Mark the `MyProps` property as [`stored=false`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties_(Delphi)#Storage_Specifiers) (or don't make it `published` at all) and then override the virtual `DefineProperties()` method to stream the `MyProps` data manually. See [Storing and Loading Unpublished Properties: Overriding the DefineProperties Method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Overriding_the_DefineProperties_Method) in Embarcadero's DocWiki, and [Streaming non-published TPersistent Properties – A Better Way](http://riversoftavg.com/blogs/index.php/2015/12/24/streaming-non-published-tpersistent-properties-a-better-way/) on the Delphi Codesmith blog.

For example:

```pascal
type
  TMyItem = class(TCollectionItem)
  private
    procedure ReadMyProps(Reader: TReader);
    procedure WriteMyProps(Writer: TWriter);
  protected
    procedure DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler); override;
  published
    MyPropsClass: TMyPropsClass;
    MyProps: TMyProps stored false;
  end;

procedure TMyItem.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
begin
  inherited DefineProperties(Filer);
  Filer.DefineProperty('MyProps', ReadMyProps, WriteMyProps, True);
end;

type
 TReaderAccess = class(TReader);
 TWriterAccess = class(TWriter);

procedure TMyItem.ReadMyProps(Reader: TReader);
begin
  MyProps := TMyPropsClass(FindClass(Reader.ReadString)).Create;
  Reader.CheckValue(vaCollection);
  Reader.ReadListBegin;
  while not Reader.EndOfList do
    TReaderAccess(Reader).ReadProperty(MyProps);
  Reader.ReadListEnd;
  Reader.ReadListEnd;
end;

procedure TMyItem.WriteMyProps(Writer: TWriter);
begin
  Writer.WriteString(MyProps.ClassName);
  TWriterAccess(Writer).WriteValue(vaCollection);
  Writer.WriteListBegin;
  Writer.WriteProperties(MyProps);
  Writer.WriteListEnd;
  Writer.WriteListEnd;
end;
```

Comment: thks for the answer, but, i'm getting a error when try save the form where is 'MyComponent'."Error reading MyComponent.commom Leng: 116.".I changed the Reader, but, no success. Could you help me?

Comment: @AnselmoMS it sounds like you are still overriding `DefineProperites()` on your `TMyComponent` after I told you several times not to, override it on `TMyItem` only. `common` is not a property of `MyComponent`, so your `DefineProperties()` should not be trying to make the DFM think it is. Please edit your question to show your latest code.

Comment: No. I'm using a separated package that use you code. I'll edit my question as current complete code

Comment: Note: when removed `Writer.WriteString(MyProps.ClassName)` writes normally, but get a error (error 6) on Read properties

Comment: `Writer.WriteString()` and `Reader.ReadString()` is the whole key to solving your original issue, so you can't really omit them.

Comment: My current code is the same in my question no changes, and the read error persist.

Comment: @AnselmoMS Then you are just going to have to debug into it to figure out where it fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206388/discussion-between-anselmoms-and-remy-lebeau).